# Hibernate exception when saving entity

Tags: hibernate

I'm currently facing a problem where by some unknown reason hibernate layer is throwing the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.company.EntityForSave#12345]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1935)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2579)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2479)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2806)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:114)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:268)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:260)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:180)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
```

Does anyone have some idea was this is happening?
I read multiple articles about this but none of them is applied to my situation so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Well it sounds like the row was updated or deleted by some other action.  What do your logs say?  What's your code look like?  Do you have any logging going on in the database?

Comment: I can't show the code! Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was that transactions were overlapping. In open nested transactions, dirty read of data can cause serious damage.